# Cordova Plugin Variables between fetch.json and config.xml

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

So I'm building a cordova app and it utilize the Facebook Login plugin (but the question appplies to any other plugin as well). Sometimes I want to change the Facebook APP_ID that the plugin connects to, so i assumed the following flow would work:

**First.** Change the variables in config.xml with the new Facebook ID

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~1.7.1">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="1728167004731036" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="QuickShop Sandbox" />
</plugin>
```

**Second.** Do a `cordova prepare` followed by a `cordova build --release android`

However the following files keeps to have the old variables that were specified in `fetch.json` when installing the plugin.

```
platforms/android/android.json
platforms/android/res/values/facebookconnect.xml
platforms/android/build/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merger.xml
platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/values/values.xml
```

Does the variables in `fetch.json` overrides the ones in `config.xml`, how can I do the opposite. What the best way to instruct Cordova to always use the plugin variables in `config.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to explain few things, You need not have to explicitly add the plugin in config.xml as its not a mandate and also if required you can add it automatically using `--save` option rather than doing it manually. For example,

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save`

This command adds the plugin and adds the entry automatically to config.xml

Also fetch.json is a file that tracks installed plugins, their origin and revision like npm package.json This file is updated on cordova add/remove plugins. When we `cordova prepare`, cordova reads plugin list from plugins/ios.json (in case of ios), get the plugin infos from plugins/fetch.json and try to find the plugin locally.

So if gotta instruct cordova to always use the plugin variables in `config.xml`, follow steps below:

- Define plugins dependencies in config.xml (use `--save` option preferably)
- Remove platforms and contents inside plugins folder
- Run `cordova platform add PLATFORM_NAME` command

This ensures that plugin info is config.xml is always honoured

Comment: thats pretty much what im doing, i have the plugin dependency in config.xml using the <plugin> tag, i remove the adnroid platform, and then i added it again. However, the variables from the plugin is retrieved from fetch.json and not config.xml

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam You gotta knock of the contents inside plugins folder as mentioned in step 2. As fetch.json is the key file which holds reference to plugin versions locally

Comment: so i just delete the fetch.json file?

Comment: @Yehia cleaning complete plugins folder should be fine.

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam Was that answer helpful? Did you resolved it?

Comment: coming back again to this issue, removing the plugin folder each time i change the APP_ID takes foreever, do you think there is a better solution?

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam Suggest you to look at this SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816035/using-environment-variables-parameterizing-config-xml But even using hooks, you gotta remove and add android platform atleast