# Apache Cordova : use different settings in config.xml for debug and release

Tags: cordova

I am looking for a way to use different settings in the `config.xml` file : some settings for a debug build and other settings for a release build.

For example I need to use this for a debug build :

```
<content src="https://staging.mywebsite.com" />
```

And change to this for a release build :

```
<content src="https://www.mywebsite.com" />
```

I also need to change values in some `<preference />` and `<variable />` tags

Cordova-CLI's `build` command doesn't seem to have any parameter to specify a `config.xml` to use for the build

For the moment, the only way I can find to do this is to rename my `config.xml` to `config-debug.xml`, duplicate it to `config-release.xml` and change some values in it. And when I need to build, rename the xml I want to use to `config.xml`

This is not very convenient :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use different environments that are defined in command line, you could create a template `config.xml` (the file is `config.tpl.xml`) and a `before_prepare` cordova hook to replace the variables in the template with the correct values and save the generated content in `config.xml`.

*The hook is:*

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var compile = require('es6-template-strings/compile');
var resolveToString = require('es6-template-strings/resolve-to-string');

var ROOT_DIR = process.argv[2];
var FILES = {
    SRC: "config.tpl.xml",
    DEST: "config.xml"
};

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev';
var envFile = 'src/environments/environment.' + env + '.json';

var srcFileFull = path.join(ROOT_DIR, FILES.SRC);
var destFileFull = path.join(ROOT_DIR, FILES.DEST);
var configFileFull = path.join(ROOT_DIR, envFile);

var templateData = fs.readFileSync(srcFileFull, 'utf8');

var configData = fs.readFileSync(configFileFull, 'utf8');
var config = JSON.parse(configData);

var compiled = compile(templateData);
var content = resolveToString(compiled, config);

fs.writeFileSync(destFileFull, content);
```

I use the environment variable as `NODE_ENV` here, if you use another (like `APP_ENV`) just do the corresponding changes in the hook above. The hook loads a json from `src/environments/environment.[env].json`, like `environment.dev.json` or `environment.prod.json` (it can be changed in the hook above).

*In `config.tpl.xml`:*

```html
<content src="${CONTENT_URL}" />
```

It would turn into `${CONTENT_URL}` into the correct url, based on the environment file used (you need to have a property `CONTENT_URL` in the environment json files).

For more info, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46345926/4850646

Comment: But what to do if the action was stopped in the middle? I mean, after the config.xml file was restructred

Comment: @Raz What is the problem you see? I would have 2 files `config.tpl.xml` and `config.xml`, and a hook would update `config.xml` based on the template defined in `config.tpl.xml`. But in the end cordova would only see the `config.xml` file (that already has the correct values).

Comment: Lucas this is exactly what I am doing now :)

Comment: Hey Lucas, how do you add new plugin for example, do you add it to the config.tmplate.xml or the config.xml? If you add to the config.xml how do you update the template config? manually?

Comment: @Raz I add to the template, because the `config.xml` is overwritten at every build.

Comment: I found out how to solve this. Using after add/rm plugin hook is updating the template. Before prepare hook updates the real config. Thats it :)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**:  Ok this IS working for me.  I just needed to update the paths to load common.xml and write config.xml.

I am toying around with using one of the hooks, probably the before_prepare and before_run.  I need to test it out but this could suffice

I placed my config.xml into a subfolder I created so it doesn't get overwritten, or you can just rename it.  And then I use xml2js to load, parse, and also rebuild back to xml.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const fs = require('fs');

const parseString = xml2js.parseString;
const builder = new xml2js.Builder();

const stagingDeploymentKey = "YOU_STAGING_KEY";
const productionDeploymentKey = "YOU_PROD_KEY";

/************************************************************
 * load our commong config xml and parse it into a JS object
 */
var commonXML = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../configs/common.xml').toString();
var commonObj;
parseString(commonXML, function (err, result) {
  commonObj = result;
});


module.exports = function(context) {
  // default to staging key
  var CodePushDeploymentKey = stagingDeploymentKey;

  // cordova build ios --release
  if (context.opts.options.release === true) {
    // set KEY to production one
    CodePushDeploymentKey = productionDeploymentKey;
  }

  // replace value in with proper environment specific key
  commonObj.widget.platform[1].preference[0].$.value = CodePushDeploymentKey;

  // write the xml file to the root director of the project so cordova can read it
  var xml = builder.buildObject(commonObj);
  fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/../config.xml', xml);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no exact solution for your problem. But you can look up in this plugin. I hope this will quite helpful for you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config

Comment: Will this plugin respond to different env variable?

Answer (score 0):

I'd made two copies of *config.xml*: *config.Debug.xml* and *config.Release.xml* (I have two configurations).

Then I had added  line to MSBuild target file (*Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets*) that copies the intended file to config.xml before compiling:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)config.$(Configuration).xml" 
DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)config.xml"
Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)config.$(Configuration).xml')"
></Copy>
```

Downside of this method is that you need to keep a copy of this file, as it will be overwritten on every TACO update.

Answer (score 0):

**gulpfile.js**

```
    const gulp = require('gulp');
    const Config = require('cordova-config');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var argv = require('yargs').argv;

    gulp.task('config', function () {

        let data;
        let env = argv.channelTag;
        if (!env || env === 'dev') {
            data = fs.readFileSync('src/environments/environment.ts', 'utf-8');
        } else {
            data = fs.readFileSync('src/environments/environment.' + env + '.ts', 'utf-8');
        }

        let startIndex = data.indexOf("{");
        let lastIndex = (data.indexOf("}")) + 1;

        let configEnv = JSON.parse(data.substring(startIndex, lastIndex));
        console.log(configEnv);

        const configXml = new Config('config.xml');

        configXml.setID(configEnv.appId);
        configXml.setName(configEnv.appName);
        configXml.setVersion(configEnv.version);
        configXml.setAndroidVersionCode(configEnv.versionCode);


        // Write the config file
        configXml.writeSync();
    });
```

**environment.ts**

```
     export const environment = {
      "production": false,
      "appId": "in.xyz.abcDev",
      "appName": "MyApp Dev",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "versionCode": "1000"
    };
```