# Removing a directory before Cordova build

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

In my hybrid project, I have a node modules directory which does not need to participate in the apk construction.

By reading the [cordova documentation about hooks](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html#Hooks%20Guide), I ended up with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// before_build_android.js

console.log("*** running before build ***");
const spawn = require('child_process').execSync;
console.log(spawn("pwd").toString("utf-8"));
console.log(spawn("rm -rf ./platforms/android/assets/www/node_modules").toString("utf-8"));
console.log("*** done ***");
```

And in my config.xml I have it referenced:

```
<!-- ... -->
<platform name="android">
    <hook type="before_build" src="hooks/before_build_android.js"/>
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<!-- ... -->
```

However it does not work.

Any guidance about how to remove this in order to avoid it to be added to the .apk file? `node_modules` is too big and all I need is the build.js generated by browserify.

Comment: You need some assistance in making cordova hooks work or you are looking for scripts to remove your directory?

Comment: @gandhi i need a hook however an external script might be useful

Comment: have you tried this using an absolute path?

Comment: @Sombriks Please let me know if you were able to crack this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest option would be is to use a batch file that does the job of removing the unwanted directories and hook the batch file before the cordova build operation kicks in.

Have wrote a sample script earlier which invokes a batch file that reads the value of a variable from environmental variables and update the config.xml file before adding android platform. You can refer the hook in the following [link](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Hooks) you can extend on this to knock off the unwanted directories before android build using a similar hook.

Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816035/using-environment-variables-parameterizing-config-xml) for more info on hooks. This post also has a solution for hook implementation in non windows bases operating system. Hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: thank you for your effrort, indeed the cleaner approach will involve external scripts instead of a hook.