# Cordova config.xml environment variables

Tags: cordova, ionic3

## The Scenario:

I'm building an `Ionic3` application, and my `config.xml` have some data that I want to be able to change according to my environment (for example, I want that my facebook app id have different values for development, staging and production).

I achieved this creating a template `config.xml` (the file is `config.tpl.xml`) and a `before_prepare` `cordova` hook to replace the variables in the template with the correct values and save the generated content in `config.xml`.

The `cordova` hook uses the `npm` package [`es6-template-strings`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-template-strings):

```
npm install es6-template-strings --save-dev
```

*The hook is:*

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var compile = require('es6-template-strings/compile');
var resolveToString = require('es6-template-strings/resolve-to-string');

var ROOT_DIR = process.argv[2];
var FILES = {
    SRC: "config.tpl.xml",
    DEST: "config.xml"
};

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev';
var envFile = 'src/environments/environment.' + env + '.json';

var srcFileFull = path.join(ROOT_DIR, FILES.SRC);
var destFileFull = path.join(ROOT_DIR, FILES.DEST);
var configFileFull = path.join(ROOT_DIR, envFile);

var templateData = fs.readFileSync(srcFileFull, 'utf8');

var configData = fs.readFileSync(configFileFull, 'utf8');
var config = JSON.parse(configData);

var compiled = compile(templateData);
var content = resolveToString(compiled, config);

fs.writeFileSync(destFileFull, content);
```

I have files in the `src/environments/` directory for different environments, that are chosen based on the `NODE_ENV` value that is defined when I build `cordova`. For example, if `NODE_ENV=prod` (production), then it would use the file `environment.prod.json`:

```json
{
    ...
    "FACEBOOK_APP_ID": "11111111",
    "FACEBOOK_APP_NAME": "My Facebook App Name",
    ...
    "PUSH_SENDER_ID": "22222222",
    ...
}
```

When the hook is executed, this part in the `cordova.tpl.xml`:

```xml
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~1.7.4">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="${FACEBOOK_APP_ID}" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="${FACEBOOK_APP_NAME}" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.9.2">
    <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="${PUSH_SENDER_ID}" />
</plugin>
```

becomes like:

```xml
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="~1.7.4">
    <variable name="APP_ID" value="11111111" />
    <variable name="APP_NAME" value="My Facebook App Name" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.9.2">
    <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="22222222" />
</plugin>
```

## The problem:

So far so good. The problem is that when some automatic changes are done to `config.xml` (like adding plugins), it is not reflected in `cordova.tpl.xml`, so I have to remember to make the changes manually.

Although the way it is done now is still much better than having to add each environment variable like before (it was a maintenance nightmare and error prone), I still have to change the template every-time a add/change/remove a plugin (not so frequent, and easy to discover the problem when I forget it, but still far from the ideal).

## My question:

I would like to know if there is a way avoid these manual changes, but keep using the environment variables like I'm doing now.

It could be achieved making the automatic changes to `config.xml` to be done to `config.tpl.xml` instead (like when adding a plugin with `--save`), if possible, but I haven't found any `cordova` option about this.

Or using the `config.xml` as the template and send it to another place with the variables defined (e.g. to `www/config.xml`), and use the `config.xml` in the other location to be used to build the app (not the `config.xml` in the root, i.e., the template). I would only change the `src` and `dest` files in my hook (to `config.xml` and `www/config.xml`, respectively). But I also haven't found a way to achieve this.

Any thoughts about this?

*(It doesn't need to be an Ionic specific solution.)*

## Update (2017-10-13)

Based on [Bobby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46698231/4850646)'s answer, I achieved what I wanted both when installing and uninstalling a plugin. I've created 4 hooks: `after_plugin_add`, `after_plugin_rm`, `before_plugin_add`, `before_plugin_rm`.

The `before` hooks copy the template (`config.tpl.xml`) into the `config.xml` file and the `after` hooks do the inverse.

The `before_plugin_add` and `before_plugin_rm` hooks are as follows:

```javascript
#!/usr/bin/env node
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var ROOT_DIR = process.argv[2];
var FILES = {
    SRC: 'config.tpl.xml',
    DEST: 'config.xml'
};

var srcFileFull = path.join(ROOT_DIR, FILES.SRC);
var destFileFull = path.join(ROOT_DIR, FILES.DEST);

var templateData = fs.readFileSync(srcFileFull, 'utf8');
fs.writeFileSync(destFileFull, templateData);
```

The `after_plugin_add` and `after_plugin_rm` hooks are almost identical, just swapping `FILES.SRC` and `FILES.DEST` values.

Comment: Thanks for this! One note: This line ```var ROOT_DIR = process.argv[2];``` doesn't work in my case because process.argv[2] is resolved to "prepare". What works in my case is `var ROOT_DIR = '';`. I'm using Ionic 4 and Cordova CLI 9.0.

Comment: Another question: Do you add config.xml to .gitignore? From my point of view it would make sense to not have it checked in.

Comment: @KlemensZleptnig I add `config.yml` to `.gitignore`. I don't know how to get the root dir in an Ionic4 hook :/ In a cordova project the above should work, though. You use them as a cordova hook or ionic is handling it behind the scenes? I think Ionic4 is adding arguments. You could try to log them like `console.log('1', process.argv[1])`, `console.log('2', process.argv[2])`, `console.log('3', process.argv[3])`, and so on.

Comment: I use them as Cordova hooks, just like you described it. Ionic calls Cordova, when I execute `$ ionic cordova prepare android --no-build` it will run `cordova prepare android`. These are the argv: `[ '~/.nvm/versions/v10.16.0/bin/node',
  '~/.nvm/versions/v10.16.0/bin/cordova',
  'prepare',
  'android' ]` when I do a `console.log(process.argv);`. But as I wrote, it works if I just use a relative path based on the project root.

Comment: I'm having some issues with the plugin hooks (the prepare hook works great). I have a template string for the resource file `<resource-file src="${ANDROID_GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON_FILE}" target="app/google-services.json" />`, so Cordova complains with his error message: `Source path does not exist: ${ANDROID_GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON_FILE}` because it seems to check the if the path exists.

Comment: @KlemensZleptnig The variable `${ANDROID_GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON_FILE}` should be only in the template file (`config.tpl.yml`) and not in the file `config.yml`. If `cordova` is complaining then maybe you have that variable in the generated file (`config.yml`). Give it a look and see if this is the case.

Comment: But isn't the idea of exchanging the files that during installation of the plugin, 
 `config.tpl.yml` becomes `config.xml` so that the new plugins get added to it, and after installation, this is reverted?  According to that logic - if I understood it right - during installation, there will be variables in `config.xml`.

Comment: @KlemensZleptnig This topic is a bit old so I forgot about that :P. It seems that depending on where you put the variable (in your case, it represents a path) cordova could give errors, so I don't know if you should use the hooks I mentioned. **What I recommend you to do** (and it's what I normally do), **is defining plugins directly in the file `config.tpl.yml`** instead of adding them from the command line, so that when the preparation step is done, the plugin is installed, and you shouldn't need hooks nor copying code from `config.xml` to the template.

Comment: How did you keep the ${FACEBOOK_APP_ID} variables in tpl file on after_hooks?

Comment: @IraklisBekiaris I'm not using the above code for some time so I'm not sure about your problem, but **I think that your `before` hook is not being called**. If the `before` hook is called `config.yml` receives the contant of `config.tpl.yml`, then the plugin is installed, and after the installation the `after` hook is called, making the `config.tpl.yml` file receive the content of `config.yml` that has the new plugin, and `${FACEBOOK_APP_ID}` will remain the same, because the config file received the template content initially. **So make sure that the `before` hook is being called.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution could be to create hooks for **before_plugin_install** and **after_plugin_install**.

```
On before_plugin_install copy the cordova.tpl.xml to cordova.xml.
... Plugin is installed ...
On after_plugin_install copy cordova.xml to cordova.tpl.xml
```

Comment: How did you keep the ${FACEBOOK_APP_ID} variables in tpl file on after_hooks?

Comment: ${FACEBOOK_APP_ID} is part of the template. So, you copy the template on top of the original file. Install the new plugin. This should not affect the ${FACEBOOK_APP_ID} variable. Then make this file a template again.