# Cordova hook to change application ID based on environment variables

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, configuration, cordova-hooks

I have 3 different environments where depending on the environment in use, the application id and name (as well as other variables like cloud URLs) are different.

What I want, is to implement a Cordova hook that automatically makes the modifications to the config.xml file without having to do this manually.

I have managed to do this for the

```
<resource-file src="src/certificates/${CERTIFICATE_PATH}" target="src/certificates/${CERTIFICATE_PATH}" />
```

as well as for other variables.

The environment files:

```
environment.common.ts
environment.a.ts
environment.b.ts
environment.c.ts
environment.ts
```

I have this **before_platform_add hook**:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const compile = require('es6-template-strings/compile');
const resolveToString = require('es6-template-strings/resolve-to-string');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = function (ctx) {
    const FILES = {
        SRC: "config.tpl.xml",
        DEST: "config.xml"
    };
    const ROOT_DIR = ctx.opts.projectRoot;
    const srcFileFull = path.join(ROOT_DIR, FILES.SRC);
    const destFileFull = path.join(ROOT_DIR, FILES.DEST);
    const templateData = fs.readFileSync(srcFileFull, 'utf8');

    let environment = helpers.getEnvironment(ctx); // I am getting the environment (a, b, or c) in JSON format via parsing the ts file with regex
    let config = helpers.getHookConfig(environment); // This is a JSON object with keys config.APPLICAITON_ID, config.APPLICATION_NAME, config.CERTIFICATE_PATH, ...
    
    var compiled = compile(templateData);
    var content = resolveToString(compiled, config);
    fs.writeFileSync(destFileFull, content);
};
```

How it works (inspired by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345603/cordova-config-xml-environment-variables)):

> config.tpl.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="${APPLICATION_ID}" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>${APPLICATION_NAME}</name> 
    ...
```

> config.xml after the hook:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="the_ID" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>the_Name/name>
    ...
```

The name and ID are successfully updating.

**THE PROBLEM**

Let's suppose that it is the first time I am building the application.

I do it like this:

> cordova platform remove android

> cordova platform add android --variable **var1=true**

```
The hook prints correct environment variables depending on --variable var1=true
```

and after the hook, the terminal prints:

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^9.0.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    **Package: var1**
    Name: a_name
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-29
```

After that, if I do

> cordova platform remove android

> cordova platform add android --variable **var2=true**

```
The hook prints correct environment variables depending on --variable var2=true
```

and after the hook, the terminal prints:

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^9.0.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    **Package: var1** //STACKS IN VAR1
    Name: a_name
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-29
```

So, although the hook does its job and changes the app_id and app_name at config.xml, the cordova still caught the previous app_id and 'thinks' that the previous package needs to be used. So the config.xml listens to the new app id but the cordova to the previous one.

**ERROR THROWN:**

```
No Java files found that extend CordovaActivity.
```

Any ideas on whether the cordova caches the package name or anything would be much appreciated.