# Gradle get current included file path

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I'm building an cordova plugin that needs to do a custom build.
I need to get the file relative to the included gradle file path that is being included by the [gradleReference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html).

Both the options above gives the project gradle path ($APP_ROOT/platforms/android)

```
println "${projectDir}"

println file('.')
```

Is there a way to get the file correct path?

Comment: Check out my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356833/cordova-android-requirements-failed-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gra/44592751#44592751 and see whether you can infer something from that file

Comment: Ok so I should kinda build a hook because on gradle itself it's not possible ?

Comment: you can try out a before build hook it it helps. I was referring to the link as the js file contains the logic to fetch gradle path that you are looking for

Comment: Got it.It's more a workaround than I would like but I think I'll take it

Comment: shall i post that as answer?

Comment: Sure. Just give me a sec to see how to use it and I accept it

Comment: Ok Just to be clear. My idea is that on the included gradle plugin that was done trhough gradleReference the source path of the plugin is the root gradle not the included. And you are saying that you are not aware of away of getting this path using only gradle and that I should either modify the chek_req and solve it in JS world right?

Comment: I think the answer i posted should be clear for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `check_reqs.js` file under `platforms\android\cordova\lib` folder That file contains the logic to get the gradle path that is getting used. Just replicate the same wherever applicable in your case.

If you require some more info on hooks that you were talking about, check out this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816035/using-environment-variables-parameterizing-config-xml/38475946#38475946)