# While app is running on an Android device, how can I programmatically get the name of the APK file used for installation?

Tags: android, cordova, apk

In my code, is it possible to check if the app is running on an Android device, and if so, return the name of the APK file used to install the app on the device?  In my case, that name is `app-debug.apk`.

The motivation for the question is that I’d like to give the APK a custom name, then when the app is running on the device, to execute some custom code, and set some custom configuration, based on the name of the APK.  Maybe there is a better process to achieve that?

On Stack Overflow, I've seen many questions about how to change the APK name before the build, but none on how to programmatically check the APK name. I've also seen questions about how to check the APK name using native Android code.

Thanks.

Comment: "Maybe there is a better process to achieve that?" -- use [product flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants).

Comment: OK thanks.  I should have maybe been clearer that I'm using the Cordova framework to create my app.  I think it is possible to use Android flavors with Cordova, but it seems to be a little involved from what I've seen.  But I took your suggestion to heart and found another solution to implement the custom configuration I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question to let people know how I resolved this issue.  The short answer is that I never figured out how to read the APK name.  I achieved the custom configuration I wanted by reading something else.

**More Info**

In my case, the customization I wanted to do was solely to my project's `config.xml` file.  My original thought was to read the APK name from my code, and make customization (e.g. change the logo file) based on its value.  But instead, I ensured the custom edits were made based on an environmental variable I passed to the build command via the command line.  And I ensured this customization occurred on every build, using a Cordova hook.  That solution was something I saw in [this separate Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816035/using-environment-variables-parameterizing-config-xml/46345926#46345926).